# @types/node not showing types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've installed `@types/node`

In an `index.ts` files, the default node modules are of type `any`

`const fs = require('fs');`

`fs` is any.

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "cwd": "/Users/georgenorris/Code/take-homes/simple-chat",
    "projectSearchDir": "/Users/georgenorris/Code/take-homes/simple-chat"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "./.ts-node"
  }
}
```

Is my tsconfig file

Why don't the types show up?

Answer (score 0):

`require('modulename')` is considered a dynamic import by typescript. So doesn't think it can reliably know what types to import.

In typescript you want to use the `import` keyword.

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwM4ElzXgqERwOTJ4CwAUAPRlxVUB6A-KaQMYQB2SmSASgKYCOcALxwo-AK7BRACgJI8ASlIVqtOkA)